# App in Google Play Store is incompatible for any device even if in the console it's compatible with all

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

We've uploaded about a dozen hours ago our first Unity3D APK to GPlay.

Even if the google publish console the APK seems compatible with any device (over 4000) in the GPlay page it seems incompatible with all the devices.

Here is the Android manifest generated by Unity and that we can't edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="3" android:versionName="1.2" package="com.quattrosrl.flappy" android:installLocation="auto">
   <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
   <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityPlayerActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
</activity>
<activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
<activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="\ 439801112817728" />
 </application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: You can edit the manifest by copying it to the Assets/Plugins/Android-folder

Comment: yeah but what's wrong on it?

Comment: Where are you seeing a message that it's incompatible? On the Google Play store web site?